# Are Maneuver Pre-Reqs like Feat Pre-Reqs?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have a level 19 character that has 16 levels of Warblade and 3 levels in non-initiator classes.  Due to the way initiator levels are determined, I qualify for my first 9th-level maneuver at this level.

My character has three Diamond Mind maneuvers, and I have my eyes on getting Time Stands Still.  I need four Diamond Mind maneuvers to get Time Stands Still.  I also get a stance this level, so I get Stance of Alacrity - a Diamond Mind stance.  Stances count as maneuvers for the purpose of determining pre-reqs.  However, I still question if I am eligible to get Time Stands Still from a timing perspective.  Taking feats happens in a sequential order.  For example, a Fighter can take Cleave as his second level 1 feat if he has taken Power Attack as his first feat.  However, gaining maneuvers is a part of a class ability.

So, my question is this: Can I take my stance and maneuver in a certain order and, thus, get Time Stands Still at this level, or does the choosing of the stances and maneuvers happen at the same time?  If it is the latter, I suspect the fact that I took a qualifying stance this level won't register on time, thus meaning I will have to wait until next level to get Time Stands Still.  Any insight on this matter would be most appreciated.

Comment: Check out this http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35277/3-5-tome-of-battle-warblade-maneuver-replacement-and-maneuver-prereqs?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, you can qualify for *time stands still* by taking *stance of alacrity*

The official level-up rules specify a particular stage during level-up for choosing class features, but *not* the order in which class features are chosen. Thus, the order is up to you. Once you choose *stance of alacrity*, you know it, and it is a Diamond Mind maneuver, and thus counts towards the prerequisites of *time stands still*.

Note this is generally far more important for Tiger Claw initiators at 1st level: only *wolf fang strike* lacks the prerequisite of knowing 1 Tiger Claw maneuver, so if you want more than one maneuver from Tiger Claw at 1st level, you **must** take *wolf fang strike* first and then take others (most importantly, *sudden leap*).

Comment: Can you quote or link the level-up rules? I'm under the impression that "all class features are chosen in the same step" could as well mean they're all chosen at the same time, so one can't be a prereq for a different one.